# Dovecot Sieve and :output variable for execute adding invalid character

Tags: dovecot, sieve

I'm trying to get blow Sieve filter to work

```
require ["fileinto", "imap4flags", "mailbox", "body", "envelope", "vnd.dovecot.pipe", "variables", "vnd.dovecot.execute"];

if envelope :matches "To" "*@*" {
  set "recipient" "${0}";
  set "user" "${1}";
  set "recip_domain" "${2}";
}

if envelope :matches "From" "*" {
  set "sender" "${0}";
}

#Check if recipient is valid user
if execute :output "valid_user" "user-verification" "${recipient}" {
    if string :matches "${valid_user}" "True" {
      if body :raw :contains ["message/notification"] {
        setflag "\\Seen";
        fileinto :create "Notifications";
        stop;
      }
    }
}
```

Where `user-verification` is an extprogram which calls API and verify user based on email address then returns boolean (as an output to the console).

Everything works fine when I will remove `if string :matches "${valid_user}" "True"` statement other way it looks like is not recognizing `valid_user`variable.

When I pipe `valid_user` to some script just to capture value for that variable it throws an error:

> error: specified :args item `True?' is invalid.

Why question mark was added to the variable in this case?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case "True" is followed by a newline, which Sieve happily reads and includes in the variable value.

To have it fixed `user-verification` script must to output it without a new line.